# Flutter - RangeError (index)

Tags: flutter

I am getting "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4: 5" error in my flutter app.

Error
[image]

This is my code and I hope somebody is able to help me fixing the error:

```
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/models/beach_model.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/models/popular_model.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/screens/selected_place_screen.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/widgets/bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/models/recommended_model.dart';
import 'package:fluttertravelapp/widgets/custom_tab_indicator.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  // Page Controller
  final _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.877);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBarTravel(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: ListView(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            // Custom Navigation Drawer and Search Button
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 57.6,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 28.8, left: 28.8, right: 28.8),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 57.6,
                      width: 57.6,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.6),
                        color: Color(0x080a0928),
                      ),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_drawer.svg'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 57.6,
                      width: 57.6,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.6),
                        color: Color(0x080a0928),
                      ),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_search.svg'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              // Text Widget for Title
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 48, left: 28.8),
                child: Text('Explore\nthe Nature', style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplay(
                  fontSize: 45.6,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),),
              ),

              //Custom Tab bar with Custom Indicator
              Container(
                height: 30,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.4, top: 28.8),
                child: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 4,
                  child: TabBar(labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.4, right: 14.4),
                    indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.4, right: 14.4),
                    isScrollable: true,
                    labelColor: Color(0xFF000000),
                    unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xFF8a8a8a),
                    labelStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                    unselectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                    indicator: RoundedRectangleTabIndicator(
                        color: Color(0xFF000000), weight: 2.4, width: 14.4
                    ),
                    tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text('Recommended'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text('Popular'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text('New Destination'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text('Hidden Gems'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],),),
              ),

              //ListView Widget with PageView
              //Recommendations section
              Container(
                height: 218.4,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16,),
                child: PageView(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _pageController,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: List.generate(
                      recommendations.length,
                          (int index) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => SelectedPlaceScreen(
                              recommendedModel: recommendations[index])));
                    },
                        child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.8),
                    width: 333.6,
                    height: 218.4,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.6),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(recommendations[index].image),
                        ),
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 19.2,
                            left: 19.2,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.8),
                              child: BackdropFilter(
                                filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                                sigmaY: 19.2, sigmaX: 19.2),
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 36,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 16.72, right: 14.4),
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/icon_location.svg'),
                                      SizedBox(width: 9.52,),
                                      Text(recommendations[index].name,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 16.8,),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                    ),
                  ),
                      )),
                ),
              ),

              //Dots Indicator
              //Using SmoothPageIndicator Library
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.8, top: 28.8),
              child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                controller: _pageController,
                count: recommendations.length,
              effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
                activeDotColor: Color(0xFF8a8a8a),
                dotColor: Color(0xFFabababab),
                dotHeight: 4.8,
                dotWidth: 6,
                spacing: 4.8,
              ),
              ),
              ),

              //Text Widget for Popular Categories
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 48, left: 28.8, right: 28.8),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Popular Categories',
                      style: GoogleFonts.playfairDisplay(
                        fontSize: 28,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        color: Color(0xFF000000),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Show All',
                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                        fontSize: 16.8,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Color(0xFF8a8a8a),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              //ListView for Popular Categories Section
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 33.6,),
                height: 45.6,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: populars.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.8, right: 9.6),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 19.2),
                      height: 45.6,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.6),
                        color: Color(populars[index].color),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(width: 19.2,),
                          Image.asset(populars[index].image,height: 16.8,),
                          SizedBox(width: 19.2,),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),

              //ListView for Beach Section
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 28.8, bottom: 16.8),
                height: 124.8,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: beaches.length,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.8, right: 12),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return Container(
                    height: 124,
                    width: 188.4,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.6),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(beaches[index].image),
                      )
                    ),
                  );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want the full code you can see the code from https://github.com/abdulazizahwan/flutter_travel_app
I tried the same code.

Comment: Where are you getting `recommendations` variable from?

Comment: There is a dart file in lib/models there we use recommendations you can see that file from the github link.